# Error formatting doubles

Tags: dart, number-formatting

This statement:

```dart
new NumberFormat("#.##").format(12.33)
```

throws this error:

> "Class 'double' has no instance method '&'"

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: fixed a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9215

I guess you don't need to worry about it, it should be fixed soon.